# ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: cmd.exe, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to follow a tutorial and one of the things I need to do is npm install -g generator-meanjs. After I run that i get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\zach\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "generator-meanjs"
    npm ERR! node v4.2.3
    npm ERR! npm  v3.5.1
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\zach\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-meanjs\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\decompress-tarbz2\node_modules\seek-bzip\node_modules\commander
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR! syscall rename

    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\zach\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-meanjs\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\decompress-tarbz2\node_modules\seek-bzip\node_modules\commander' -> 'C:\Users\zach\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-meanjs\node_modules\commander'
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\zach\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-meanjs\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\decompress-tarbz2\node_modules\seek-bzip\node_modules\commander' -> 'C:\Users\zach\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-meanjs\node_modules\commander'
    npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
    npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! code 1
```

It tells me to rename

C:\Users\zach\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-meanjs\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\decompress-tarbz2\node_modules\seek-bzip\node_modules\commander' ->

but I do not know what to rename it to. Can anyone clarify this error for me?

It also has a debug log but it's extremely long.

Comment: Try renaming it to what's shown on the right side of the arrow (`->`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting the folder generator-meanjs and reinstalling it as administrator using windows powershell.